# Why $* or % does not work in this makefile?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Consider the following simple makefile:

```
define cat_deps
    $(shell cat $(1).dep)
endef

TARGET := main.o
all:$(TARGET)
    @echo  Done...!

%.o:$(call cat_deps,$*)
    @echo $*
```

In target `main.o` variable `$(1)` in `cat_desp` must be `main`
but it is empty string. Also `$(call cat_deps,%)` does not work 
and in this case variable `$(1)` becomes `%`. Note 
that file `main.dep` exists. Please help me.

Comment: As a rule of thumb, every `$` which you don't want to be interpreted by `make` should be doubled. In particular `$`-s occurring in commands to be interpreted by your Unix shell.

Comment: "a rule of thumb" you are right, but a simple question instead of reading manual when time is valuable seems better. Sorry for low-level question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In target `main.o` variable `$(1)` in `cat_desp` must be `main` but it is empty string.

`$1` in `cat_deps` actually expands to `main`, if you pass `main` to the function `cat_deps`. However, you are passing an empty string. In your rule:

```
%.o: $(call cat_deps,$*)
    @echo $*
```

the `$*` above is expanded *before* the rule is being matched, and before that rule being matched, the automatic variable `$*` is actually empty.

---

You need to make use of [*secondary expansion*](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Secondary-Expansion.html) in order to expand both the function call to `cat_deps` and the automatic variable `$*` *after* the rule is matched, i.e.:

```
.SECONDEXPANSION:
%.o: $$(call cat_deps,$$*)
    @echo $*
```

Note the additional `$` for both `call` and `$*`.

---

Note that you also need the following rule without recipe:

```
%: %.o
```

in order to suppress that implicit rule. Otherwise, a prerequisite of the new `%.o` rule above could match that (not-suppressed) implicit rule, which has a `.o` file as prerequisite, and will, in turn, match the new `%.o` rule again.